# What do the operator and arrow opetions mean when used together in Maple procedures?

Tags: maple

Let's say I have the following procedure definition in Maple:

```
CaesarCryptAnalysis :=
proc(ciphertext)
options operator, arrow
table([seq(Decode(ciperthext, encoding = alpharot[k]), k = 0 .. 25)])
end proc
```

I do not exactly get what the `operator` and `arrow` options are supposed to do.

Based on poking around, when I deleted the `options operator, arrow` row, the output changed to:

[image: output without options]

from

[image: output with options]

I would guess thus, that this is only a cosmetic change?

If someone could link the official documentation explaining this, it would be great, I did not manage to find it.

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly it is a cosmetic thing.

Those options are explained on the Help page for [procedure options](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=option).

In particular, it states,

*Option **operator** declares to the Maple system that the procedure was entered and is to be printed and otherwise manipulated as an operator. Thus,*

```
f := x -> x^2-1;
```

*is equivalent to*

```
f := proc(x) option operator, arrow; x^2-1 end proc;
```

*Option **arrow**, in conjunction with option **operator**, indicates that the operator was initially entered using the -> notation. The use of option **arrow** also disables Maple simplification rules that add any non-local names in the operator expression to the parameter list.*